# Счётчик кликов по ссылке с сохранением в базу данных и выводом MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется база данных с таблицей в которой хранятся статьи.
её структура:

```
Поле        Тип          Null   По умолчанию    Комментарии     MIME
id          int(11)      Нет             
title       varchar(100) Нет             
title_en    varchar(100) Нет             
description text         Нет             
text        text         Нет             
mini_img    varchar(100) Нет             
author      varchar(100) Нет    Администратор        
date        datetime     Нет             
views       int(11)      Нет    0        
keywords    text         Нет             
category    varchar(100) Нет
```

В поле views хранится количество просмотров.

В виде в цикле foreach формируется ссылка на каждую статью: `<a id="add_v" href="<?=base_url();?>index.php/article/<?=$item['title_en'];?>">Читать далее→</a>`

Какое условие написать в контроллере и функцию в модели, чтобы значение поля views из данной таблицы при клике на данную ссылку увеличивалось на один и сохранялось в базу?